# C# Coverting 1px mouse movement to different resolution

Tags: c#, coordinates, screen-resolution

I've built custom control pad instead of mouse and written application to pick up movments but possible coordinates are in range of max width: 320px and max height: 240px, since i would like to control my mouse with control pad I need a way to convert coords from res 320x240 to different screen resoultions ie 1280x720 so when my control pad pointer is at coords of 160x120 my mouse would be at middle of screen. Does any one have any solution or code snippet that I can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use floating point and something like this to convert from `0`..`low_res_maximum` to `0`..`high_res_maximum`

```
low_res_coordinate * high_res_maximum / low_res_maximum
```

E.g.:

```
high_res_x = low_res_x * 1280.0 / 320.0;
```

Comment: Great.  To explain, you divide the coordinate by the maximum it could be to get a value from 0.0 to 1.0 (0% to 100%).  Then you multiply by the maximum you want, which makes it from 0 to the new maximum.